# Union different fields from different tables and return data using refcursor plsql

Tags: plsql, union-all

I am trying to display multiple select results using union all:

```
    SELECT USERNAME, NAME, SURNAME, null as description FROM t1
    union all
    SELECT null as username, null as name, null as surname, description as  company FROM t2
```

As written the query return username, name, surname and description null. But, I want to take description from t2 where the column is not null

I am looking to display this situation:

```
    USERNAME, NAME, SURNAME from t1, description from t2
```

t1 as 3 fields ( USERNAME, NAME, SURNAME) and t2 1 field (description).

How can I do that?

Comment: In that case you can simply join the two tables. Why are you taking Union All. It would a cartesion product bt you wil get your result.

Comment: You must JOIN t1 and t2 somehow. But since description is null on t1 and {username,name,surname} is null on t2. How do you expect to match rows from both tables?

Comment: I can't join the 2 tables. I have to union the result

Comment: @EmanueleAntico Please update your question to include sample data in both tables and the results you want to get. Also, why can't you join the two tables?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the information you provided the best suited query for your requirement would be as below. PS that this would be producing cartesian result.

```
SELECT t1.USERNAME, t1.NAME, t1.SURNAME,t2.description
FROM t1
Join 
t2
On t2.description is not null
```